# Relation between CPUs/Cores vs tomcat thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, jmeter, load-testing

I am performing load test on a system using JMeter.  I check my server has 32 cores found by

```
nproc –all
```

in tomcat my Connectors configuration is:

```
<Connector port="8001" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="300" acceptCount="100"                 connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
 <Connector port="9001" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="300" acceptCount="100"                 connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" scheme="https" proxyPort="443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

If I increase the maxThreads the response time of the tomcat is increase . I am using MySQL for my data source. My question is how tomcat maxThreads is related to os thead.

Comment: They are the same thing.

Comment: More likely the _real_ question is to find the bottleneck when increasing the load on your application, and you gave the focus on the threads number. By the way redirectPort don't seem necessary in your config. And are you really proxying anything ?